# accessing Access 2007 System Object tables and schemas

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am looking for some help on retrieving Access 2007 database schema information for system object tables. I have reviewed, read and tested this successfully for the non system tables. The database tables info I am trying to retrieve are in the tables that begin with MSys{xxxxxxxxxx} and store things like relationships, creation date, dateupdate, etc. This tables are viewable by right clicking on the Navigation Options popup menu in Access and selecting Show System Objects.

For clarification, I have added the System.mdw database to the connection string, and I have attempted multiple settings in the restrictions property of the getSchema method. I am using ado.net, vb.net, and VS2008, these are access 2007 databases not mdb files.

My issue appears to continue to be no read access to the System tables. My end goal is to manage relationships initially and eventually hopefully script these databases much like can be done EASILY (Microsoft) in SQL Server Mgmt Studio.

I am hoping someone can point me to some good web link resources or even a good book that clearly discusses this functionality.

thanks,

Comment: So you are just looking for tutorials on basic manipulation of Access 2007 through vb.net?

Comment: I am looking for anything that will help to resolve this, I am a proponent of supporting literature in learning technologies. I have found that many concepts have not been well recorded in text certainly in part because of the speed in advancement of tech, this is where web links come in. They are faster to evolve and easier to update. But sample code is also very good.

Comment: So you are trying to modify .accdb databases using vb.net?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the details on this part, they are Access 2007 DBs that were orginally 2003. There are no USER permissions on these dbs.

Comment: Are you looking to use code to change these permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the easiest way to gain access to the system table data is to execute a permissions command on the Systems database table(s). The following query did the trick....

```
    Dim strDdl As String = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
    Dim command12 As New OleDbCommand(strDdl, connection)
```